# Python Conversion from different text editors

Tags: python

I use Sublime Text for PHP, HTML, CSS, etc. I decided to learn Python and learned something very weird. Indentation is important for `if` statements I was confused on why this didn't work:

```
if len(original) > 0:
print original
   else:
print "empty"
```

Turned out because I indented the `else`. My question is this: If I use Sublime Text and convert to Notepad or Atom, won't the indentation change and bug out?  Sorry for the weird question.

Comment: The indentation in your question is incorrect before you get to `else`. Anything you intend to be inside the `if` condition should be indented.

Comment: Most editors will put line spacing in for you, and convert tabs to 4 spaces to avoid issues. I'm not sure what you're asking beyond that.

Comment: I think you need to realise that indentation is part of the language, i.e. indentation level is important to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will not happen. The indentation will be converted to 4 spaces (1 tab correspnds to 4 spaces). 
If you open a Python file in an IDE such as Sublime Text, PyCharm, or Visual Studio Code, ... all indents will be applied as 4 spaces (if nothing else is set).

First of all you will need to understand, how to use indentation in Python. I also recommend that you use a code checker, such as Pylint. This helps, for example, if you forget an indent or haven't indented correctly.

Your Code should look like this:

```
if len(your_string) > 0:
    print("something")
else:
   print("something else")
```

Using a code editor, usually supports you, when you are coding. If you hit <kbd>return</kbd> after the first line: `if len(your_string) < 0:` it will automatically add 4 spaces after line break.